How can I find out what is automatically controlling and enabling/disabling the network adapters?
I am using Windows 10 Enterprise edition.
As soon as a network cable is plugged into my ethernet port, the LAN adapter automatically gets enabled and the Wi-Fi adapter gets disabled. Not just disconnected from Wi-Fi, disabled the adapter. When I manually re-enable the Wi-Fi adapter, it stays enabled until I try to connect to a Wi-Fi network when it is automatically disabled again.
Ethernet is a domain network. Group policy settings are set to allow simultaneous connections.
I have another laptop that theoretically has the same "core load" software package and it works perfectly fine without disabling adapters, but this desktop disables adapters. Both machines appear to have the same group policy settings and are running the same operating system. The Wi-Fi adapter is a USB adapter. I tried plugging it into the laptop and the laptop still works fine.
I do not have admin rights to the domain network.
How can I find out what is automatically controlling and enabling/disabling the network adapters?

Which operating system is use? The mention of "Group policy settings" suggests might be running a version of Microsoft Windows.

Sorry, forgot to mention that. Windows 10 Enterprise.

@David_M16 please update the question ... right now, it still does not say which OS you are using ... comments are not for important info

@David_M16 - You should [edit] your question instead of submitting important relevant required information in a comment.

Done. Sorry about that.

This question should include more details and clarify the problem.

This is a business environment (Win10 Enterprise and a domain network)? Are you technical staff of the business, or have you spoken with your designated technical staff yet?

@Ramhound What other details do you need to know?

@music2myear Yes I am part of technical staff but not specifically IT. I work with the data systems group. The level of our IT department that I can contact is of no help for this.

Would this question be better asked over at ServerFault?

@David_M16 - It doesn’t contain enough information to diagnose your problem

@Ramhound I would be happy to provide any info you need to help, I just don't know what else would be useful info.

So the machine is connected to an AD domain. What polices are active on the domain that might explain the behavior. Are you an Administrator on the domain? Many of diagnostic steps I can suggest will require elevated permissions.

@Ramhound I do not have access to any of the settings or parameters of the domain network, I am not an administrator. I suppose its worth noting, I have another machine that was theoretically configured with the same settings, the same "core load" software, and it works perfectly fine. So I do not think it is domain or network related, I think it is specific to the desktop. I will edit the post to contain this info.

While you may not find your designated IT staff to be helpful, they are the correct people to resolve this for you. They have the required administrator rights, they are aware of the policies applied to your computer, and they have the responsibility for making sure your computer works to the requirements of the employer. This is one of the primary reasons that questions about corporate computers are off topic on this site.

@David_M16 - You need to have your Administrator troubleshoot this problem in that case.

Its so hard to ask for help these days. All of our IT tech support people seem to be from India and don't seem to speak English well enough to even understand the issue. I have admin rights on the computer in question, just not the domain network itself. I feel certain it is a setting on the computer itself since another computer that is supposed to be set up the exact same works fine. Oh well, thanks for your time.

Is there no windows log file or something that shows what would be controlling the network adapters. The closest I could find in Event Viewer is network logs of when the adapters and network changed state and UAC access requests, but I didn't see anything showing what specifically was turning the adapters on and off. Maybe I'm not looking in the right place?
